# Nested classpath entry can not be represented in Maven model and will not be visible to non-OSGi aware Maven plugins

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

The title almost says it all. I'm getting this warning:

> [WARNING] Dependency from ..\gui to nested classpath entry ..\org.jboss.hibernate\resources can not be represented in Maven model and will not be visible to non-OSGi aware Maven plugins

The build passes, but still I would like to know how to resolve the reported problem?

Answer (score 1):

Due to restrictions in the maven project model, nested dirs on an OSGi bundle's Bundle-ClassPath cannot be represented on the maven compile classpath.
This does not affect the compile classpath for the tycho-compiler-plugin (it supports all nested jar/dir scenarios), but only other maven plugins (e.g. javadoc, PMD, findbugs,...) you may additionally configure in your tycho build.
These maven plugins are not OSGi-aware and rely on the maven project/classpath model.

See https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/TYCHO-483?focusedCommentId=125868&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-125868

I don't think there are ways to solve this other than avoiding nested jars/dirs altogether.

Since this only affects other maven plugins, can't be fixed easily and the warning seems to confuse users, I'm wondering if we should log it in debug mode only instead.